# Is there a way to register a dll on a server as part of a build?

Tags: vb6, build-automation, dllregistration

I'm trying to build our web application automatically. I need to be able to copy the VB6 DLL's to a server and register them since the webapp is using them as a backend. I can't seem to find a way to register them from another machine. I can't use rsh because it isn't allowed on this server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a ASP.NET form in a separate ASP application, that accepts DLL paths to register and schedules a batch file (with job ID, timestamp and sequence number in filename to uniquify) to run with Windows Scheduler at the start of the next minute, outputting register result to a result text file.  And which deletes older time stamp batch and result files.  And which supports status code/text output enquiry/return for previous jobs.  And call this ASP interface from the command line over the network using a C# script.  Yuck.  Really really horrible rickety rickety solution and might be more work than the application (itself).

Borland C++ used to include a remote commands tool I believe, a decade ago.  And there's plenty of tools for remoting.

But without suitable arbitrary remote commands or shells *permission*, looking for remote registration, you're options are limited.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was afraid of.